# Is a phrase followed by a that clause specific?

Tags: articles

[From a textbook](https://www.studocu.com/en-ie/u/4292555)

> A probabilistic model is a mathematical description of an uncertain situation.
> It must be in accordance **with a fundamental framework** that we discuss in this
> section. Its two main ingredients are listed below and are visualized in Fig. 1.2.

The "fundamental framework" is a phrase followed by a that clause which describes it. Therefor, the "fundamental framework" is specific, which means the textbook should say

> ... It must be in accordance **with the fundamental framework** ...

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No it's not. This is an example where either the definite or indefinite article fits. It's a bit like referring to **a dog that we saw** or **the dog that we saw**. The construction allows either usage, depending on the context.

Comment: When they first mention the framework, the "that" clause making it specific hasn't been uttered yet. After having introduced that framework with "a", to refer to that same framework they would have  to use "the". But they could have used "the' on the first introduction, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indefinite article serves to introduce an object not previously named or referred to. So long as this author did not previously make any reference to this particular fundamental framework, it is correct English to refer to it as "a fundamental framework."

The definite article can introduce an object previously referenced, or introduce a new object which is in some way unique. For example, if you write "...**the** fundamental framework that we discuss in this section," you are implying that there is only one fundamental framework discussed in this section. The indefinite does not by itself carry this implication (but in context, I would be rather surprised if there were more than one).

Comment: Your answer is very informative. Thank you. With your help. I guess I got it. "a fundamental framework that ..." is grammatically correct and make some kind of implication that there might be more than one fundamental framework. In contrast, the definite article indicate clearly that there is only one fundamental framework discussed in this section. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @RobertH: Yes, in general, but in this particular context, I think more than one would be unlikely (because the whole point of sections is to divide and organize the topic into discrete chunks; you would not choose to put two fundamental frameworks in one section).

Comment: Thank you. So, in this particular context, "the fundamental framework" is perfect (better than the other), "a fundamental framework" is fine, right?

Comment: They're both fine, although "the" is a bit more explicit. But there's no rule that you have to include as much information as possible.